# JQuery Mobile Custom Theme Buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

I just started using a jquery mobile custom theme instead of one of the defaults. Lots of issues...but the current one is that dynamically created buttons don't work as expected.

I have some dynamic html I'm injecting via $("#container").append(...)

```
            <div>
                <a class="view-it" data-role="button" href="">View</a>
            </div>
```

Because it's dynamic, I need to do

$("*[data-role='button']").button();

to get it to initialize.

Although my button now looks like a button, the anchor instead still looks like a hyperlink and the click event only fires when clicking on the hyperlink inside the button, not on other areas of the button itself.

Any ideas?

Update:

If I use a div like so instead of an anchor

```
            <div class="view-it" data-role="button">
                View 
            </div>
```

It displays correctly now, but still doesn't respond to clicks across the entire button's surface...only around the text (+ a tiny bit of margin)

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: 1.4.1 of jquery mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-role=button` is deprecated so you need to add classes manually and it doesn't require any manual enhancement even if you append them dynamically. `.button()` is used for `<input type=button>` only.

Your solution is as follows:

```
var Btn = '<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-Custom ui-btn-icon-Position ui-icon-Name">Button</a>';

$(".selector").append(Btn);
```

- `ui-btn-Custom`: is theme swatch i.e. `ui-btn-a`
- `ui-btn-icon-Position`: icon's position, left,right,top,bottom or notext i.e. `ui-btn-icon-left`
- `ui-icon-Name`: icon's image i.e. `ui-icon-home`

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/a5Q3A/)**

Comment: so I actually need to add every class instead of saying data-role='button' for every button??

Comment: @jeff yes, exactly. It's deprecated and will be removed in 1.5. You'll notice that there are no `span`s' wrapped in anchor tag. It's straight forward and faster in processing.

Comment: one step forward, four back

Comment: @jeff haha..JQM has deprecated many widgets to enhance performance. If you still want to use `data-role` then use `.buttonMarkup()` instead of `.button()`. It's also deprecated and will be removed but it works for now.