# json2htmled jQuery mobile button inside table td looks old, has old button inside new one after button()/refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button, json2html

I'm using this transform to build a jQuery mobile button inside of a regular table 'td':

```
{
    "tag":"button",
    "type":"button",
    "id":"${idPrefix}-delete",
    "data-role":"button",
    "data-mini":"true",
    "data-icon":"delete",
    "html":"Delete"
}
```

but it renders as an old HTML button.

After I manually refresh the button, it looks like a mobile button with the icon, but the old button is "minified" inside of it.

How can this be fixed?

---

**missing `::before`?**

I just compared it to a normal looking mobile button, and the problematic button is missing the `::before` right before the `<button>` tag.

---

I removed all of the mobile attributes and tried to call `button()` later, same result.

Comment: `$("button").button();` to enhance it.

Comment: Oh okay, I missed that ;) which version are you using? Can you post rendered html?

Comment: JQM version? 1.4 or before?

Comment: Your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22079455/1771795 buttons and anchor tags are treated the same. No need to use any kind of enhancement. Add classes directly and that's it.

Comment: @Omar Yessir!  Normally, I would delete, but I think considering how fast jquery mobile's moving, this might provide some benefit to someone later.  Would you mind upgrading to an answer?  Thank you so very much and in advance!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49437/discussion-between-omar-and-gracchus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To speed up web app initializing and to increase jQuery Mobile's performance, the team decided to drop `.buttonMarkup()` widget and replace it with classes.

There is no longer `data-role=button`, `data-mini=true`, etc... All are replaced with classes as follows.

To convert a button or an anchor into a jQM button, just add `ui-btn` class. To add an icon with position `ui-btn-icon-left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`. Icon's image `ui-icon-bars`, `delete`, `info`, etc. Mini button/anchor `ui-mini`. Button's theme `ui-btn-a` or `b`.

```
<button class="ui-btn ui-mini ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-delete">Button</button>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/N5UgF/)